# Get URL backlinks

Tags: php, google-search

I am trying to create a script to get the amount of backlinks to particular URLs - the method I am currently using is to query the google search API for `link:example.com/foo/bar` which returned the amount of results - I used that value to estimate the backlinks.

However, I am looking for alternate solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic approach would be to log `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` on every incoming request, which is the URL of the site linking to your site. I'm sure there are some caveats to this approach (i.e. conditions under which Referer is not sent, potential for being spammed through bogus Referer URLs), but I can't speak to all of them. The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer) may be a good starting point.

There are also [pingbacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pingback)/[trackbacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trackback), but I wouldn't rely on them.

Comment: Quite often, if it's a spambot they're sending you a bogus referrer also.  I do a blanket-disregard of all referrers send with an IE6 UA because of this.

Answer (score 0):

Pingbacks / Trackbacks are to determine hits from a particular website. These are manual, rather than automatic, and are meaningful when there is a HIT from them.

However, the approach you did till now, is something that involves a huge cache of links and backlinks.

Either there must be some kind of database to track the nodes of connection between two pages, or you must start builiding your own.

Use the available ones, and better build a mashup of more than one database. But, if you want to have  strong system built, then verify the backlink from your system, and then maintain the cache at your end too. The cache should include the verified backlinks only.

I hope this works.

Comment: And another main reason the trackbacks / pingbacks might not work is that not all the sites with a backlink send a trackback RPC to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I think http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/ and their api might be of more help.